# rdfs:subPropertyOf and rdfs:domain

Tags: rdf, ontology, rdfs

Is the following statement possible?

```
:a rdfs:subPropertyOf :b
:b rdfs:domain :aDomain

Thus, :a rdfs:domain :aDomain
```

Comment: it's quite obvious given that `:a rdfs:subPropertyOf :b` means `a(x, y) -> b(x, y)` and that `:b rdfs:domain :aDomain` means `b(x, y) -> aDomain(x)`

Comment: In RDFS or OWL? See https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-41335-3_7.

Comment: @StanislavKralin in RDFS.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: [Stanislas Kralin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7879193/stanislav-kralin) is asking the right question here, but the link he refers to may be a bit obscure, although it is spot on in term of relevance. The [answer by IS4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67940228/1260887) is only valid if you consider OWL semantics, not with RDFS alone.

Answer (score 0):

Are these two statements possible?

```
:a rdfs:subPropertyOf :b .
:b rdfs:domain :aDomain .
```

Certainly. The first states that every `:a` of something is also `:b`, and the seconds states that every object of `:b` is an `:aDomain`.

Is this statement possible?

```
:a rdfs:domain :aDomain .
```

Yes, it states that every object of `:a` is an `:aDomain`.

Is it implied by the first two statements, meaning that adding this statement to a graph already containing the two does not change whatever can be inferred about the known individuals? Yes. In the first case, being an object of `:a` implies also being an object of `:b`, and thus being an `:aDomain`, which implies that an object of `:a` is an `:aDomain`, exactly what the statement says.

Answer (score 0):

> **TL;DR:** according to the RDFS semantics, if everything that has property `:a` also is of type `:aDomain`, it does not automatically imply that `:a rdfs:domain :aDomain`; according to the OWL semantics, if everything that has property `:a` also is of type `:aDomain`, it logically implies that `:a rdfs:domain :aDomain`.

The answer to this question is more subtle than it may seem because there is a slight difference between the semantics of RDFS and that of OWL. [Stanislav Kralin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7879193/stanislav-kralin) highlight this subtlety in his laconic comment to the question. The RDF snippet given by [Costas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13410944/costas) can be interpreted according to the [RDFS semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#rdfs-interpretations) or the OWL semantics (or even the [RDF semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#rdf-interpretations), or the [simple semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#simple-interpretations), or other [semantic extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#dfn-semantic-extension)).

According to simple semantics and RDF semantics, the terms `rdfs:subPropertyOf` and `rdfs:domain` do not have any special meaning and therefore the conclusion `:a rdfs:domain :aDomain` does not hold.

According to RDFS semantics, the conclusion does not hold either, but it is less obvious. In RDFS, if you have:

```
:a rdfs:subPropertyOf :b .
:b rdfs:domain :aDomain .
?x :a ?y .
```

for any IRI or blank node `?x` and any IRI or blank node or literal `?y`, then you can conclude that:

```
?x rdf:type :aDomain .
```

but you cannot conclude that:

```
:a rdfs:domain :aDomain .
```

This is because RDFS does not have an **extensional semantics**. This means that if everything that has the type *C* also has the type *D*, you cannot conclude (from this alone) that *C* is a subclass of *B*, and if everything that has the property *p* has type *C*, then you cannot conclude (from this alone) that *p* has the domain *C*. In 2004, RDF 1.0 presented an alternative version of [RDFS with extensional semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-mt/#ExtensionalDomRang), that highlighted the issue. In 2013, Franconi et al. discussed [The Logic of Extensional RDFS](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-41335-3_7) and its properties (link also provided by Stanislas Kralin in his comment to the OP).

Finally, OWL semantics (both the [Direct Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/) or the [RDF-based semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-rdf-based-semantics/)) has an extensional semantics, so the conclusion holds when interpreting the RDF snippet according to these semantics:

```
:a rdfs:subPropertyOf :b .
:b rdfs:domain :aDomain .
```

entails (that is, logically implies):

```
:a rdfs:domain :aDomain .
```